# Specifying agent at queue build time with TFS 2015

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild

Is it possible to configure a build so you can set which agent you want it to run on when you manually queue a build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any special in your scenario?

Generally, in VSTS you can select which agent (Hosted) you want to run directly when you manually queue a build:

---

**UPDATE：**

If you are using on-premise TFS (TFS 2015 in your scenario) or Private agent for VSTS. Then you can set **Demands** when you queue a build.

You can also queue build with the REST API and specify the **demands** which match the specific agent:

e.g.:

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/",
   [string]$projectName = "0323ScrumTFVC",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$BuildDefinitionId = "1",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

function CreateJsonBody
{

    $value = @"
  {
  "definition": {
    "id": $BuildDefinitionId
  },

  "sourceBranch": "$/0323ScrumTFVC",
  "demands":["Agent.Name -equals AgentNameHere"]
 }           

}
"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody

$uri = "$($collectionurl)/$($projectName)/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added "2015" to the title because that's what we're using. It appears 2017 caters for this now, so I'll push for an upgrade. Cheers!

Comment: @BenPower  **VSTS** is specific for `Visual Studio Team Services` (TFS online) and the screenshot above was captured from VSTS. Based on your clarification you are using TFS on-premise 2015, generally we called it TFS 2015. The behavior will be the same on all version of on-premise TFS (vNext build, including and later than 2015). That means we can only set the **Demands** to achieve that even if you upgrade to TFS 2017.

Answer (score 4):

It appears this is the only way on VSTS 2015:
[image]

No friendly drop-drown menu so you have to type it in.

Comment: Yes, for on-premise TFS or private agent for VSTS we can only set Demands to match the agent which you want to run with it. See my updated answer.