# How to set a different default TFS agent pool

Tags: tfs

We have multiple agent pools in TFS. Is there a way to set the default agent to one of the pools?
Currently, all project builds has a Default agent when creating a build.
Instead of the Default agent to display as the first one on the list, we want to have a different agent as default. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of the Default agent to display as the first one on the list, we want to have diff agent as Default. Is it possible?

I am afraid there is out of box setting to set a different default agent pool.

On the web portal, we could select the different default TFS agent pool in the option **Default agent queue** in the build Options tab and **save** it:

[image]

This setting is saved. When you queue the build, the default agent pool will be the agent you set above:

[image]

And when you next queue your build, the default agent will be the one you set before.

On the other hand, we could add a specify the **demands** which match the specific agent, like:

```
Agent.Name -equals AgentNameHere
```

[image]

Then queue build with the REST API and specify the demands:

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/",
   [string]$projectName = "0323ScrumTFVC",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$BuildDefinitionId = "1",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

function CreateJsonBody
{

    $value = @"
  {
  "definition": {
    "id": $BuildDefinitionId
  },

  "sourceBranch": "$/0323ScrumTFVC",
  "demands":["Agent.Name -equals AgentNameHere"]
 }           

}
"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody

$uri = "$($collectionurl)/$($projectName)/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

Ticket here: [Specifying agent at queue build time with TFS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49971599/specifying-agent-at-queue-build-time-with-tfs-2015).

**But**, **this method is not work for UI**.

Check the document [Predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and [Demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=tfs-2013&tabs=yaml).